# Periodic background fetching in Flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, background, scheduling

I'm looking forward to the best approach to do the periodic task scheduling for iOS in the background using Flutter. I tried with both 'workmanager' and 'backgroung_fetch' package but it seems workmanager isn't ideal for iOS yet, it works with android well but not with iOS ideally. On the other hand, with 'background_fetch', I'm not sure how to schedule the periodic event here in the background. Can anyone suggest to me in which way, I should proceed? Actually, my app's objective is to get the data from an external BLE device periodically with different time intervals in the background when the app is even not running, I mean in the close state.

Comment: There is no way to execute code in the background at a specific time on iOS.  You can use background fetch, or the newer [`BGTaskScheduler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler) and while the latter gives more control over when your app will run neither allow you to specific exactly when your app will run.